# Android Studio 3.0 (MacOS 10.13) AVD Crash Laptop

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, qemu, macos-high-sierra

Every time I try to launch an AVD in Android Studio 3.0, it crashes my entire laptop.  I'm on MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra), and the crash happens when qemu launches (it never gets close to actually emulating a device).  I have deleted all existing AVD devices, uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio, the emulator (and HAXM), and even used homebrew to install qemu separately (to see if there was a different version that would NOT crash).

I have no idea where else to look or what else to do... I can run my app successfully on my phone that is connected, but just can't use the emulators at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your cpu does not support virtualization?

Comment: It did with whatever version of Android Studio I had before (hadn't developed anything for a few months, then it updated to 3.0 and hasn't worked since).

Comment: i am having trouble starting the emulator.  i don't get any errors output and even the emulator64-crash-service crashes after the crash!  i booted into a different profile and it worked fine so it must be something to do with my setup